# Catch 22 and Derby user authentication needed for in memory database

Tags: sql, authentication, derby

I'm trying to use Derby for an in memory database. I picked Derby because the SQL is closer to DB2 in SQL than H2. My problem is that it is a new database, so it needs to be created. However, Derby wants to create an unsecured database, secure it, but then shut it down so that the next session can be authenticated. The problem is, shutting an in-memory database down removes it.

I've seen the steps to turn on authentication. I can't get past this catch 22 issue. The sample code I'm working with is at https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/devguide/rdevcsecure26537.html

```
import java.sql.*;

public class AuthExampleEmbedded {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
        String dbName="jdbcDemoDB";
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";create=true";
        Connection conn = null;

        // Load the driver
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            System.out.println(driver + " loaded.");
        } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("\n Make sure your CLASSPATH variable " +
                "contains %DERBY_HOME%\\lib\\derby.jar (${DERBY_HOME}/lib/derby.jar). \n");
        }

        // Start the database and set up users, then close database
        try {
            System.out.println("Trying to connect to " + connectionURL);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
            System.out.println("Connected to database " + connectionURL);

            turnOnBuiltInUsers(conn);

            // shut down the database
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Closed connection");

            /* In embedded mode, an application should shut down Derby.
               Shutdown throws the XJ015 exception to confirm success. */
            boolean gotSQLExc = false;
            try {
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                if ( se.getSQLState().equals("XJ015") ) {
                    gotSQLExc = true;
                }
            }
            if (!gotSQLExc) {
                 System.out.println("Database did not shut down normally");
            } else {
                 System.out.println("Database shut down normally");
            }

            // force garbage collection to unload the EmbeddedDriver
            //  so Derby can be restarted
            System.gc();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            errorPrint(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Restart database and confirm that unauthorized users cannot
        //  access it
        connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:" + dbName;

        // Load the driver again
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            System.out.println(driver + " loaded.");
        } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("\n Make sure your CLASSPATH variable " +
                "contains %DERBY_HOME%\\lib\\derby.jar (${DERBY_HOME}/lib/derby.jar). \n");
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            errorPrint(ee);
        }

        // Try to log in with no username or password
        try {
            // this should fail
            System.out.println("Trying to connect to " + connectionURL +
                " without username or password");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
            System.out.println("Connected to database " + dbName);

            // if it doesn't, close statement and connection
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Closed connection");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            errorPrint(e);
        }

        // Log in as a user with read-only access
        try {
            // connection should succeed, but create table should fail
            String newURL = connectionURL + ";user=guest;password=java5w6x";
            System.out.println("Trying to connect to " + newURL);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(newURL);
            System.out.println("Connected to database " + dbName +
                " with read-only access");

            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE t1(C1 VARCHAR(6))");

            // if it doesn't, close statement and connection
            s.close();
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Closed connection");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            errorPrint(e);
        }

        // Log in as a user with full access
        // Create, update, and query table
        try {
            // this should succeed
            String newURL = connectionURL + ";user=mary;password=little7xylamb";
            System.out.println("Trying to connect to " + newURL);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(newURL);
            System.out.println("Connected to database " + dbName);

            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE T1(C1 VARCHAR(6))");
            System.out.println("Created table T1");
            s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('hello')");

            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM T1");
            rs.next();
            System.out.println("Value of T1/C1 is " + rs.getString(1));

            s.close();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            errorPrint(e);
        }

        // Remove table, then remove users previously created
        // If you don't remove the table, you will never be able to find it,
        //  because it was created by a user who no longer exists and with a
        //  default connection mode of noAccess
        try {
            //Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            //s.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE T1");
            //System.out.println("Removed table T1");
            //s.close();

            turnOffBuiltInUsers(conn);

            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Closed connection");

            // Shut down the database
            /* In embedded mode, an application should shut down Derby.
               Shutdown throws the XJ015 exception to confirm success. */
            boolean gotSQLExc = false;
            try {
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                if ( se.getSQLState().equals("XJ015") ) {
                    gotSQLExc = true;
                }
            }
            if (!gotSQLExc) {
                 System.out.println("Database did not shut down normally");
            } else {
                 System.out.println("Database shut down normally");
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            errorPrint(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Turn on built-in user authentication and user authorization.
     *
     * @param conn a connection to the database.
     */
    public static void turnOnBuiltInUsers(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Turning on authentication.");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();

        // Setting and Confirming requireAuthentication
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.connection.requireAuthentication', 'true')");
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(
            "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.connection.requireAuthentication')");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("Value of requireAuthentication is " +
            rs.getString(1));
        // Setting authentication scheme to Derby
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.authentication.provider', 'BUILTIN')");

        // Creating some sample users
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.user.sa', 'ajaxj3x9')");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.user.guest', 'java5w6x')");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.user.mary', 'little7xylamb')");

        // Setting default connection mode to no access
        // (user authorization)
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.defaultConnectionMode', 'noAccess')");
        // Confirming default connection mode
        rs = s.executeQuery (
            "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.defaultConnectionMode')");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("Value of defaultConnectionMode is " +
            rs.getString(1));

        // Defining read-write users
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.fullAccessUsers', 'sa,mary')");

        // Defining read-only users
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.readOnlyAccessUsers', 'guest')");

        // Confirming full-access users
        rs = s.executeQuery(
            "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.fullAccessUsers')");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("Value of fullAccessUsers is " + rs.getString(1));

        // Confirming read-only users
        rs = s.executeQuery(
            "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.readOnlyAccessUsers')");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("Value of readOnlyAccessUsers is " +
            rs.getString(1));

        // We would set the following property to TRUE only
        // when we were ready to deploy.
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.propertiesOnly', 'false')");
        s.close();
    }

    /**
     * Turn off built-in user authentication and user authorization.
     *
     * @param conn a connection to the database.
     */
    public static void turnOffBuiltInUsers (Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Turning off authentication.");

        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.connection.requireAuthentication', 'false')");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.authentication.provider', null)");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.user.sa', null)");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.user.guest', null)");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.user.mary', null)");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.defaultConnectionMode', 'fullAccess')");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.fullAccessUsers', null)");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.readOnlyAccessUsers', null)");
        s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.propertiesOnly', 'false')");

        // Confirming requireAuthentication
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(
            "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.connection.requireAuthentication')");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("Value of requireAuthentication is " +
            rs.getString(1));

        // Confirming default connection mode
        rs = s.executeQuery(
            "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.defaultConnectionMode')");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("Value of defaultConnectionMode is " +
            rs.getString(1));
        System.out.println("Turned off all the user-related properties");
        s.close();
    }

    /** Exception reporting methods
     *   with special handling of SQLExceptions
     */
    static void errorPrint(Throwable e) {
        if (e instanceof SQLException)
            SQLExceptionPrint((SQLException)e);
        else {
            System.out.println("A non-SQL error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  // END errorPrint

    //  Iterates through a stack of SQLExceptions
    static void SQLExceptionPrint(SQLException sqle) {
        while (sqle != null) {
            System.out.println("\n---SQLException Caught---\n");
            System.out.println("SQLState:   " + (sqle).getSQLState());
            System.out.println("Severity: " + (sqle).getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Message:  " + (sqle).getMessage());
            sqle.printStackTrace();
            sqle = sqle.getNextException();
        }
    }  //  END SQLExceptionPrint
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting `derby.authentication.provider` before you create the database? And then skipping the shutdown-and-reboot part, just setting up your users and their passwords and going on with your testing?

Comment: I'd like to set that or anything before creating but I don't know how. It's an in memory database ran through Java in a JPA environment. Could you post some steps?

Comment: @BryanPendleton I found a writeup on doing your own authentication and I saw a way of turning it on before creating the database, thereby solving my catch22 problem. Thanks for that one clue--that helped immensely and despite what you might think was not obvious.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Perhaps you can contribute a writeup of your own to the Derby project and have it added to the Derby documentation or on the Derby wiki at Apache?